# Format SUM results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a query with a SUM and I would like the output to be as follows:
123,456.78

This is what I wrote

```
CAST(SUM(MyColumn) AS REAL)
```

It returns results as 123456.78. What option shall I use to get the format I wish? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, CAST(SUM(MyColumn) AS money), 1)
```

You can "hack" it by converting to to money datatype first and then to a nvarchar

P.S. I still think it's better for you to handle the formatting on the presentation layer.

Comment: It worked great, tnx a lot!